# Truncate the third column until given strings

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

INPUT:

```
W41784094   CH60104475  lasbalsrbla bla foo bar bla PT~CH60104475
W41788464   WO60444453  hellobla bla -bla foo bar 432 alaf. PT~CH60107925
W41753387   IN61026681  sim##bla-bla bla foo bar blab lba la:bla32 bla
```

OUTPUT:

```
W41784094   CH60104455  CH60104455
W41788464   WO60444453  CH60107925
W41753387   IN61026681  NA
```

**Question**: How can I truncate the third column until " PT~"?

But if there is not always a " PT~", an "NA" is needed :\

Tab is the separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more easily done using `awk` in place of `sed`; in case `awk` is an option:

```
< input awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {if ($3~/PT~/) sub(/.*PT~/, "", $3); else $3="NA"; print}'
```

Expanded:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    if ($3 ~ /PT~/)
        sub(/.*PT~/, "", $3);
    else
        $3 = "NA";
    print
}
```

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}`: sets the field separator<sup>1</sup> and the output field separator<sup>2</sup> to `TAB`, so that each `TAB`-separated string is intended as a field of a record (<sup>1</sup>) and so that the separator is printed after each record (<sup>2</sup>);
- `{if ($3~/PT~/) sub(/.*PT~/, "", $3); else $3="NA"; print}`: if the third field of the record (`$3`) matches (`~`) the regular expression `PT~` (`/PT~/`) (i.e. if it contains it), substitute the first leftmost widest match (`sub()`) of the regular expression `/.*PT~/` (`/.*PT~/`, which matches everything until the last occurence of a substring `PT~`) with an empty string (`""`) in the third field of the record (`$3`), otherwise set the third field (`$3`) to an `NA` string (`"NA"`), then print the record;

Comment: I think you meant `...sub(/.*PT~/,...`.

Comment: @WAF No I didn't, however thinking about it twice that might be safer.

Comment: It honestly doesn't look easier.

Comment: @mikeserv This might be personal. For instance I'd have upvoted your script but I don't quite understand exactly what that command does. This is pretty simple, if there's a `PT~` string, strip everything on the third field until that, string included; otherwise set the third field to `NA`, then print.

Comment: That's fair. More than fair. I should probably explain it.

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, I think that would be better, however at least for me the problem in your script is not the pattern but rather the concatenation of the commands. This is a flaw in my answer either; I tought it could be ok since *to me* `awk` is simpler to interpret, but I agree one could disagree. I'll do the same and add an explanation

Comment: There is no concatenation of commands, except where the `t`est directly follows the `s///`ubstitution to which it applies. Certainly your answer could use some explanation as well - i'm `awk` illiterate, and it makes 0 sense to me. Stringing it all together on a single line like that definitely doesn't help.

Comment: That's way better. Thank you. `sed`'s still easier though. :)

Comment: @mikeserv Following your conceptual explanation i grokked it, it was easier than it looked, I'm probably tired. You just do two substitutions, one for the lines matching `PT~` and one for those who don't, given that I understood correctly (right?). I still think `awk` it's more high-level as a language and thus easier to understand, however I prefer `sed` also as a general rule. I usually use it as long as I can do a single substitution and avoid using external scripts, in which case I switch to `awk`(or Perl), sometimes it makes life way easier, altough I agree `sed` is *way* more fascinating

Comment: You can simplify the above to this: `awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "\t" } { if (!sub(/.*PT~/, "", $3)) $3 = "NA" } 1'`

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sed -e's/\(\t.*\t\).* PT~/\1/;t' \
    -e's/\t[^\t]*/\tNA/2'
```

That should work for you, though it will only stop stripping chars at the *last* occurrence of *`PT`* in the last field on the line.

Also, depending on your `sed` version, you may have to use literal <tab> characters everywhere I use the *`\t`* escape.

The gist is to look for two tabs on a line separated by any amount of characters, and, if they are at some point followed by the string *`<space>PT~`*, then to `s///`ubstitute away all but the `\1`st `\(` captured sub group `\)` of the `/`addressed`/` pattern-space. In fairness, this relies on a limit of three fields, but the first substitution statement might be changed to read:

```
sed -e's/^\(\([^\t]*\t\)\{2\}\)[^\t]* PT~/\1/;t' ...
```

...portably, or, with GNU or BSD `sed`...

```
sed -Ee's/^(([^\t]*\t){2})[^\t]* PT~/\1/;t' ...
```

...to definitely limit the `s///`ubstitution statement only to the very first 3 fields.

In any case, the `t`est branches away if the previous substitution is successful, and so the next `s///`ubstitution replaces the 3rd tab delimited field on a line which did not match the *`<space>PT~`* string with only the string *`NA`*.

```sh
sed -e's/\(\t.*\t\).* PT~/\1/;t'  \
    -e's/\t[^\t]*/\tNA/2'       <<\IN
W41784094       CH60104475      lasbalsrbla bla foo bar bla PT~CH60104475
W41788464       WO60444453      hellobla bla -bla foo bar 432 alaf. PT~CH60107925
W41753387       IN61026681      sim##bla-bla bla foo bar blab lba la:bla32 bla
IN
```

---

```
W41784094       CH60104475      CH60104475
W41788464       WO60444453      CH60107925
W41753387       IN61026681      NA
```

Comment: +1, but I believe he does *not* want the 4 chars " PT~" (see sample output) - The OP's description of, "truncate the third column until " PT~" probably means *up to and including " PT~", which has a leading space which seems to corroborate that.

Comment: @Peter.O - oh yeah! Thanks, Peter. I'm pretty daft, sometimes.